# Skype for business - Error registering bot endpoint

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, skype-for-business

- SDK Language: C#
- Development Environment: LOCALHOST

We have developed a Skype for business bot, but we aren't able to configure the tenant in our skype installation.
[image]

It says the configuration is not complete and suggests a cmdlet New-CsHybridApplicationendpoint which actually doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The "New-CsHybridApplicationendpoint" was added with [SfB 2015 Server Update CU5 (released in May)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3061064/updates-for-skype-for-business-server-2015). Please make sure that your environment is on CU5 (via [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uclobby/2015/12/08/skype-for-business-server-component-version-using-get-csserverpatchversion/)).

*P.S.
Please keep noted the special patch process from Microsoft as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3061064/updates-for-skype-for-business-server-2015). If you miss that issues like explained [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/383-resolved-could-not-find-stored-procedure-after-installing-sfb-server-updates.html) will be seen.*